# How do I extract a word in front of another certain word?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a field of text that follows the following formats.

```
Blessed To Receive An Offer From West Virginia University ... #HailWV üíõüíô
----------
Blessed To Receive An Offer From Michigan State University ... #GoGreen üíö
----------
Blessed to receive an offer from Abilene Christian University!!! #GoWildcats
----------
Im very blessed to announce that I‚Äôve receive an offer from Pacific University! Big thanks to @CoachPatterson_  for this opportunity!
---------
After A Great Talk With @CoachRT_Cisco I‚Äôm blessed to receive an offer from Cisco College
```

I am trying to extract whatever the college's name is.

I have tried the following code

```
str_extract(df$text,'(?<=University)\\[A-Z]\\w')
```

But all it returns is NA fields?

Comment: Will capturing the 1 word before the word university work in every case? what if you have `"Michigan State University"` for example

Comment: @DanielO that is another roadblock as well.

Comment: @user13463162 can you show all the patterns.  My solution is based on the example you provided

Comment: @akrun just edited it to show different patterns

Comment: If it is University of Georgia, what do you want to extract

Comment: @akrun the whole name 'University of Georgia'. The data is coming from Twitter so it's extremely difficult to parse

Comment: Please check the updated solution

Comment: @akrun Thank you! I just ran that and unfortunately, there is a lot of miscellaneous text after that that I do not necessarily care for. How would I essentially stop it?

Comment: @akrun. Just updated to show a few real rows of my data. As you can see, it's extremely messy but for the most part follows the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

Data:

```
data <- c("Blessed to receive an offer From Texas State University.", 
          "Blessed to receive an offer from Columbia University.",
          "Blessed to receive an offer from Abilene Christian University!!!",
          "Im very blessed to announce that I‚Äôve receive an offer from University of Georgia! Big thanks to @CoachPatterson_  for this opportunity!")
```

Solution:

```
str_extract(data, "(?<=(f|F)rom\\s)[A-Z]\\w+\\b\\s(of\\s)?[A-Z]\\w+\\b(\\s[A-Z]\\w+\\b)?")
```

Result:

```
[1] "Texas State University"       "Columbia University"          "Abilene Christian University"
[4] "University of Georgia"
```